# Solving file not found in IOS app PythonInterpreter

Tags: python, pandas, pythoninterpreter

I cannot solve my FileNotFoundError in PythonInterpreter. The .csv file is in the same folder as my .py file. Thank you for your help in advance. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('A.csv')
```

This is the output:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compiler.py", line 13, in 
    df = pd.read_csv('A.csv')
  File "/usr/local/lib/py/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/py/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 457, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/py/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 895, in **init**
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/py/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1135, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/py/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1917, in **init**
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 382, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.**cinit**
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 689, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'A.csv' does not exist: b'A.csv'

Comment: T123, Try putting the full path to it to  see if it works

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are actually executing the python program in the same directory as you have the program saved. I had a similar problem recently where I had opened a project folder in vscode which contained another folder with my python script and input file. The problem was that despite the input file and the python file being in the same directory, if the python file is executed from a parent directory, the relative path which you specified in the python file is not relative to the directory where the python file is stored but rather the directory you are in when you execute the python file.